# windows 10 att wifi on a dell inspiron SocketError:no such service -o/tcp

Tags: ruby, git, sinatra

In a git command line in Windows 10 I exec

`bundle exec rackup -p $PORT -o $IP`

but then I got

> socket error: no such service -o/tcp

- My internet connection is Wi-Fi thru AT&T and
- downloaded drivers from Dell.
- Downloaded Ruby for Windows I made so my app.rb and
  config.ru to require'sinatra' and require'ruby 2.3.1'.
- Downloaded java 8 and jruby 9.
- I had to download make from gnu because it couldn't find it.

So how can I get to tell my computer where TCP is in this software compatibility mess. The last thing I did that solved a lot was to make an account at heroku this is where I am trying to launch my ruby app thru Sinatra.

Answer (score 0):

From the onlooks of the error message `socket error: no such service -o/tcp`, my mad psychic debugging "skillz" suggest that you (or someone else) somehow messed *some* string to call something (looks like it's `rackup`) so that that `-o` string ended up placed after the `:` at the end of the host part of some URL.

Since on Unix-y systems it's (usually) possible to use a string instead of a port number (so that you can do, say, `telnet somehost smtp` instead of `telnet somehost 25`), and in such a case this string is taken to stand for the name of "a service", and a special database (typically, the file named "/etc/services") is consulted to "resolve" that string into a protocol and a number. A quick demo (on a Debian system):

```
~$ getent services smtp
smtp                  25/tcp mail
~$ getent services http
http                  80/tcp www
```

So, my guess is that when you call

```
bundle exec rackup -p $PORT -o $IP
```

the `PORT` variable ends up being empty (or undefined) and —
by the Unix shell rules — the actual commands become

```
bundle exec rackup -p -o $IP
```

…which makes `rackup` supposedly take `-o` as the port number
(since that's what gets passed as the argument to `-p`);
it then supposedly tries to call `getaddrinfo(3)` passing is that `-o`
as the name of the service, which fails.

Sticking

```
set -e -u
```

and the start of shell scripts helps catching such errors.

Another approach is to execute failing scripts with

```
$ /bin/sh -x path/to/the/script/file.sh
```

so that the shell traces the executing of the script.